# Is there software to test if a wireless connection is maintained

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

My computer drops its connection to its wireless router periodically. I know this is happening, but I'm going to have to prove that to my ISP. Is there software that will consistently ping a website or something, and log/alert if the connection goes down?

Comment: Why not just ping the router? This way you can be sure the break is between you and it (as opposed to the website or you net connection being down instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a command window (Start-> Run -> Type "cmd" -> Press OK) then type

ping google.com -t

When you are done monitoring press CTRL-C and it will tell you how many lost packets there were.

Typically, however, dropping wireless is due to an old driver for your card. Be sure to get the latest version.

Also, make sure you have your connection at the top of the list in the order of preferred wireless connections. And make sure your Roaming aggressiveness is at it's lowest setting.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, you can do a very simple batch file with the following contents:

```
date /t
time /t
ping google.com >>Ping.txt
waitfor 15
```

This will ping Google every 15 seconds, and save the output along with the current date and time to a ping.txt file in whatever folder you run the batch from.